# How to set public as root - Laravel

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu-16.04, laravel-5.5

I'm running Laravel app on server (Ubuntu 16.04). I set `.htaccess` in the root of my app with content as suggested in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation#web-server-configuration):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But when I go to my site I see tree view of my app (redirect doesn't work).
Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myowneddomain.com
    ServerAlias www.myowneddomain.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myowneddomain.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What URL are you calling? Are you using localhost:80/NameOfYourProject? Can you select your project from the tree you see?

Comment: I'm calling myowneddomain.com. App is running on server not localhost.

Comment: Ok, sounds like you need to set your project's index as the default page then, since it goes straight to the server's root folder now.

Comment: @G_V I have to change `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: Yeah, if I recall correctly that should be the first call to where it starts looking for the document to show. The default is the root, the folder where all your projects are put. You'll want to redirect the server to your main page, usually named index.php. I'm not familiar with laravel but I remember having to do this for Symfony projects with XAMPP for Linux Mint, which is built on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I set

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/myowneddomain.com/public
```

accorginf to [G_V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3427079/g-v) and it was helpful!